# How do you provide a default Style for a Custom Control in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls

In UWP, if I want to specify a default style for a custom control, I'd code it up like this:

```
    public PriceControl()
    {
        // This allows the control to pick up a template.
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PriceControl);
    }
```

I can't find the equivalent in Xamarin.Forms.  How do you tell a custom control that it should use a style by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a style in App.Xaml of the typeof your control and don't give it a key just a target type and that should do the trick:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Teal" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Just replace button with your control and it's properties Into the setter's and this will be your global default style for this control!

Comment: I have a styles.xaml file for each view, is it possible to apply the theme for the customcontrol in the styles.xaml file for the view that the custom control is used in?

Comment: @Reza Yeah you should be able to do that

Comment: ha, I should have asked how, cause so far I have not been able to do that. the first answer provided here requires me to explicitly name the class in the codebehind which means i cant use it in multiple views. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/411375